# How Earth Engine resamples overviews when cloudOptimized is set to True

Tags: google-earth-engine-python-api

In Earth Engine, we can output an image to COG while setting `cloudOptimized=True` as follows:

```
// Export a cloud-optimized GeoTIFF.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: landsat,
  description: 'imageToCOGeoTiffExample',
  crs: projection.crs,
  crsTransform: projection.transform,
  region: geometry,
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
  formatOptions: {
    cloudOptimized: true
  }
});
```

What is the default resampling method when building overviews with `cloudOptimized=True`?